# Certain record in my database of PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I was making report for my student only but there is a level that contain manager,staff and student in my database for login in my PHP, how am I supposed to do when I'm collecting the total number of student in my PHP?

[image]

```
<?php
include("checklogin.php");
include("server.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = ($_POST['password']);

    $check_user = "SELECT * FROM manager WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $run = mysql_query($check_user);


    $username = mysql_result($run,0,'username');
    $level = mysql_result($run,0,'level');

    if($level == 'stuff')
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0)//user exisi in db
        {
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;

        echo "<script>window.open('stuff.php','_SELF')</script>";
        }//end numrows

        }//end level admin

        else if($level == 'manager')
            {
            if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0)
            {
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;

            echo "<script>window.open('homepage.php','_SELF')</script>";
            }
            }//end lvl manager

            else if($level == 'student')
            {
            if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0)
            {
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;

            echo "<script>window.open('student.php','_SELF')</script>";
            }
            }//end lvl student

        else
            {
            echo "<script>alert('Username or Password is incorrect!')</script>";
            }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Login</title>
    <style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image:url(assets/img/background.JPG);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
.aa{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -wekbit-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bolder;
}
.aa input[type="id"]{
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.aa input[type="password"]{
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.aa input[type="submit"]{
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:skyblue;
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="aa"
<h2>Login</h2><br>
<br/>
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER ['PHP_SELF']);?>">
  <td> Username: </td>
    <input name="username" type="id" id="username" placeholder="Please Enter Username...." required="required"><br>
    </br>
    <td> Password: </td>
    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Plese Enter Password....." required="required"><br>
    <br/>

    <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></center>

</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Never save plain text password to your database PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: This code looks about as secure as an ashtray on a motor bike

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually, I used to be able to smoke quite nicely on my GoldWing ;-) *puff puff* even at 70 mph+

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yea but if you remember the ashtray was always empty

Comment: @RiggsFolly I had the world's biggest ashtray at my disposal; no pun intended.

Comment: @Fred-ii- _at 70 mph+_ :) Subtile very subtile

Comment: And a bit of sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: so can u correct my code instead? @magnus Eriksson, im really new in my php and msql problem.. i really need help about this

Comment: SO != a tutorial site. There are books and manuals for that

Comment: [php.net](http://php.net) is an excellent resource to start at. It should be your the first stop. I've told you what to look for (and even linked to the relevant section about Prepared Statements).

Comment: OP's question is, to him, a valid question. Unfortunately the question is difficult, if not impossible to answer due to construction and his obvious lack of experience leading to confusing code. Can't we just politely say so? Most all comments are piling on criticism rather than offering any help at all.